# Как выполнить выборку работы с БД

Tags: c#

Подскажите плиз. Где прочитать или кто то уже сталкивался. Пишу приложение которое использует БД на SQL. Но есть желание вставить перед загрузкой приложения выборку с какой БД работать. Примеру SQL или SQLite. И как организовать правильно. Сейчас для работы приложения с БД использую Entity Framework 6 на подходе Code-First.

Answer (score 0):

Ну ставьте на форму ComboBox, где предлагаете варианты.

Далее, в зависимости от варианты конструируете соединение нужного типа, предварительно спросив параметры у пользователя и возвращаете IDbConnection наружу и работаете абстрагируясь от конкретной реализации СУБД.

Comment: Я бы посоветовал смотреть в сторону entity framework core...